# convert curl/rest call to python

Tags: python, python-2.7, curl

Is it possible to translate the rest call with curl to use the requests library urllib2/requests in python

```
curl -s -k -X POST -H
'Content-Type:application/knd.com.ns.systembackup+json'
--basic --user $uname:$pwd -d '{"systembackup":{"filename":"test_backup","level":"basic"}}' 'http://$ip/nit/v1/config/systembackup?action=create'
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
import urllib2

Url = 'http://ip/nit/v1/config/systembackup?action=create'
data = [{"systembackup":{"filename":"test_backup","level":"full"}}]

def encodeUserData(uname, pwd):
    return "Basic " + (uname + ":" + pwd).encode("base64").rstrip()

req = urllib2.Request(Url)
req.add_header('Accept', 'application/json')
req.add_header("Content-type", "application/knd.com.ns.systembackup+json")
req.add_header('Authorization', encodeUserData(uname, pwd))

res = urllib2.urlopen(req)
print res.read()
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do so? SO is neither a design nor coding service.

Comment: What's the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: Do yourself and other devs a favor and use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the https://www.getpostman.com/ for it.

1. Click on "Import" and paste your curl code.
   [image]
2. Click on "Code" and choose Python and then [Requests](http://python-requests.org/).
   [image]
3. Copy your python requests code
   [image]

Comment: thanks for the inputs. did helped me tackle the problem. I'm going to paste the code below

Answer (score 0):

Adding `auth` to the above answer.

```
payload = "{\"systembackup\":{\"filename\":\"test_backup\",\"level\":\"full\"}}"

Url = 'http://ac.com/nitro/v1/config/systembackup'

querystring = {"action":"create"}

headers = {

    'Content-Type': "application/knd.com.ns.systembackup+json",

    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"

    }

r = requests.request("POST", Url, data=payload, auth=(uname, pwd), headers=headers, params=querystring, verify=False)
print (r.text)
```